# How to access/read objects inside Itemreader/StaxEventItemReader correctly?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-batch

I am new to the spring batch and I have an application where for example an xml-file of flights is read and saved to a database. The whole process is already working, but due to a certain use case I also need to access the data inside the **reader object (ItemReader)**, should it is possible.
Down there is the reader-method. It is not about this method in particular, but as mentioned it is about ItemReader.

```
@Bean
public StaxEventItemReader<Flight> flightReader() {

    StaxEventItemReader<Flight> reader = new StaxEventItemReader<Obj>();
    reader.setResource(ressource);
    reader.setFragmentRootElementName("flight");

    Map<String, String> aliases = new HashMap<String, String>();
    aliases.put("flight", Flight.class);

    XStreamMarshaller xStreamMarshaller = new XStreamMarshaller();
    xStreamMarshaller.setAliases(aliases);

    reader.setUnmarshaller(xStreamMarshaller);
    
    return reader;
}
```

How can I access the flight objects inside the reader (StaxEventItemReader) object?

I actually tried to use the read() method ([Spring doc ItemReader](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/current/reference/html/readersAndWriters.html#:%7E:text=The%20read%20method%20defines%20the,element%20in%20an%20XML%20file.)), but I am always getting NullPointerExceptions.

**If the read() method is the correct way, how can you access the flight objects inside ItemReader correctly?
If not, are there other ways?**

Comment: The reader must be opened before being used to read data (see how it implements `ItemStream`). The open/update/close methods are called automatically by Spring Batch when this reader is used in a chunk-oriented step, but if you use it outside a step (like in a unit test for example), it is up to you to call these methods to honor the `ItemSteam` contract. This is probably what is causing NPEs in your case. Other than that, the second the answer by Henning.

Answer (score 1):

There is more than one way to access the items. It really depends on what you want to do with them:

- If you only want to have a look without manipulating the items, you can implement an `ItemReadListener` with its `afterRead` method, and add the listener to your step.
- The items are passed to the processor. So you can operate on them there.
- You can extend the class `StaxEventItemReader` and override the read method to include additional logic.
- If you prefer composition over inheritance, you can write a new reader that uses a `StaxEventItemReader` as a delegate.

Comment: For clarification: Actually it is a rather unusal use case I guess. For tests I need to save the flight data to a test database before starting the tests. Since the reader methods already exists it has been suggested that I should just take the Itemreader and iterate over the items, so that I can save them to the database. But currently the problem is still there, that the read() method is not working (null pointer). Do you have suggestions what should be done in this specific use case or how to correctly use the read() method ?

Comment: The reader is stateful. Once it has read all items, its `read()` method will always return `null`. If you want to use the reader twice, you'll need to create two instances of the reader.

Comment: If you inject the reader as a bean both into the job and the test, it is the same instance as beans are singletons.